# File_Field_Tag in Rails 4 nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 app. I have a form for object in which has field_for another model..

```
<%= form_for object do |f| %>

<%= f.label:name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= fields_for :reference do |f2| %>
  <%= f2.file_field_tag :file %>

<%end%>

<% end%>
```

However, I get "Undefined method 'file_field_tag'". Does anyone know if you can upload files via  nested form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because you are using **form_for** not **form_tag**.

Try to change:

```
 <%= f2.file_field_tag :file %>

 to

 <%= f2.file_field :file %>
```

[file_field documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/file_field)